# C++ library path inclusion

Tags: c++

i found C++ libraries could be included this way:

```
#include "..\example.h"
#include ".\another_example.h"
```

what is the dots used for?

Comment: [current and parent paths](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/net/shared/geoprocessing/sharing_tools_and_toolboxes/pathnames_explained_colon_absolute_relative_unc_and_url.htm).

Comment: Nitpicking, but important: you don't include a library this way, rather a file. The include directive will be processed by the *preprocessor*. The result is then *one* "translation unit" which the compiler compiles.

Comment: Forward slashes (`/`) should be used for path separators even on Windows. That is, if you want your code to be useful anywhere outside of your dev environment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are to indicate the included file paths' are **relative to the including file's actual path**.

`.` points to the including file's actual directory
`..` points to the including file's actual directories' parent diretory

Comment: You might *emphasize* that this given import directive with a *quoted* file path is relative to the *including* file's actual path -- which I suspect is not clear to the other posters  ;)

Comment: @CouchDeveloper like this? THX for the hint.

Comment: yep, looks much better  ;)

Answer (score 2):

Double dots stand for the parent directory of the currently entered path.
Single dot stands for the currently entered path on the left side of a dot and is used to show that you want a relative path.

> A relative path is a path relative to the working directory of the
>   user or application, so the full absolute path will not have to be
>   given.

If you start your path with `/` (on *nix systems) or `DRIVELETTER:` (on Windows, e.g. `D:`) then the path is absolute. If you don't - the path is relative. If path is relative - it automatically prepends the directory of your file to the path entered.

Example:

`"dir/././../dir/.."` is the directory which contains the original file. The reductions are:

`dir/././../dir/..` -> `dir/./../dir/..` -> `dir/../dir/..` -> `/dir/..` -> `.` -> working directory. We removed `./` because it's alias to the current directory. We removed `/dir/..` because we enter a directory with `dir` and get back with `..`

One of the most often used features of `./` (but in the context of a shell, e.g. `bash`) - it forces to use a relative path instead of calling an executable program in the $PATH variable. For example if you type `ls` in terminal on *nix it will list the files in the working directory. If you type `./ls` it will run executable with the name `ls` 
 in the current working directory and execute whatever this program does.

You can read more about path separators in [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29) article on wikipedia

Comment: Your examples are more confusing than clearing up the question of the OP. Furthermore, you don't explain what you mean with "working directory" or "current directory". These have other meanings in other other contexts, and are different than what is meant in this case. So, I suspect it's not clear to you either.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper, thanks for pointing out to the unclear explanation. I used terms `working` and `current` quite ambiguously. Check it out - does it look better now? Maybe I'm not very good at explaining things, but be sure that myself I understand it very well.

Comment: It's neither "current" nor "working", it's the *including* file's path where the specified path in the include directive with *double quotes* will be appended, and searched *first*. So, the resulting path may become: */Users/me/path/to/including/folder_where_including_file_resides/../foo.h*   Then, it gets normalized to */Users/me/path/to/including/foo.h*

Comment: @CouchDeveloper, I don't get the difference. If, for example, your #include statement is in file with path "/home/user/project/dir/file.cpp" and you #include "../header.h" I say that "/home/user/project/header.h" will be included. Do you mean the same?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. ;)  -> "/home/user/project/dir/../header.h" will become effectively -> "/home/user/project/header.h".  The use of "current" or "working" directory may be misleading, since this is used in a shell, where these have a different meaning. Your explanation regarding the dots and how they affect the resulting path, was always correct   ;)

Comment: @CouchDeveloper, at least that is good)I think in first edition of the post I used term `working` only once... formed as citation from wikipedia. And yes - it was used with explanation extended for the general use including a shell.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper, I made one more edit. I think my explanation is quite complicated now but I want to finally satisfy you .

Comment: A process' "working directory" (if any) or a shell's working directory, has nothing to do with the "including file's path". The including file's path is the path where it is itself located - and the preprocessor's working directory which is parsing the headers may be different.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper, IMO the author is lost with path structure in general, not just in C++ including paths... That's why I explained it the way I did.

Comment: i don't read the whole comments, but, after reading **Sasha**'s example (and, even, the update (i.e. edited comment)), i think i'm the only one whose don't understand the example... LOL
after reading **CouchDeveloper**'s example, i got the point...

btw, thanks for **Sasha** for trying to help and **CouchDeveloper** for verify

Answer (score 0):

Two dots means one directory higher than the current one. For example, if you are in the directory C:\some\directory", "..\" would be "C:\some".

A single dot refers to the current directory. So using the previous example, ".\" would mean "C:\some\directory".

Answer (score 0):

One dot is your current directory and two dots is your parent directory.

Answer (score 0):

one dot `.` is for file's directory

2 dots `..` are for file's parent directory.